# Kafka : parallel processings in a synchronous way

Tags: apache-kafka

I am having a few problems with my use of kafka.

I have 3 steps in my algorithm :

1. Calculate the distances between all points (let's say 1 million point so 1  billion distance need to be calculated) and store it
2. Find the maximum distance
3. Divide all other stored distance by the maximum

I use kafka to produce all the couple of points (i,j) to a topic A (I), then I consume those couple (II), I calculate the distance, and re-produce (i,j,distance) to a topic B(III). Finally I consume this topic B, find the max (IV), and re-consume the topic B to store it in a file with the (i,j,normalize distance) (V).

It works with one producer but it is more complicated when you add more : how can you know when to start (IV). For that you need to know that all the data produce has been consume and reproduce. Probably kafka is not the right tool for this, though it's answering some problems I have such as distributed disk space and processing.

Do you have any advice to know when multiple producer or consumer are eating the last information of a topic and how can they say it to other topic consumer ?

For a single producer I use as a final send :

```
 producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(myTopic, "done"));
```

So when the consumer consume "done" it can stop.

Comment: It is probably possible but I want to point out that what you want to achieve is batch processing. Kafka is more designed to handle streaming data and deliver it to receivers in a continous way. Maybe using a batch-oriented framework such Apache Spark would be a better fit for your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Topic Partitions to process your Produced Messages from different Producers separately, and then creating different instance of a Consumer Group (1 instance will be consuming messages from 1 partition). 
With this you can keep your same approach and scale it with partitions. 
You can check this post for more info about partitions: https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/